# Generating Swagger for Haskell union type

Tags: haskell, swagger-2.0

I have a data structure of the following form:

```
data MyType =
   Foo Int String
   | Bar Int Int
   | Baz String
```

I've manually generated an [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) `ToJSON` instance:

```
instance ToJSON MyType where
   toJSON (Foo i s) = object [
      "tag" .= ("foo" :: Text),
      "intField" .= i,
      "stringField" = s] 
   -- and so on.
```

Now I want a [Swagger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/swagger2-2.8.4) schema for it. Because I have a custom `ToJSON` instance I'm going to have to define a matching instance of `ToSchema`. I could just declare it as a list of mostly-optional field names and a mandatory `tag` string, but it really ought to list the possible `tag` values and associate them with different fields.

The OpenAPI specification talks about [the `discriminator` object](https://swagger.io/specification/#discriminator-object) for doing this, and I've found the corresponding function in the Haskell swagger2 package. But I can't see how to get the mapping from discriminator value to sub-schema. Does anyone have any examples of how to do this?